# Insert zero values for unexisting groups in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm writing a simple query on `Amazon Redshift` as follows:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM created_at) AS year,
       EXTRACT(month FROM created_at) AS month,
       member_id,
       COUNT(*) as pageviews
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY year,
         month,
         member_id
ORDER BY year,
         month,
         member_id
```

This gives me the following result as an example:

```
year    month   member_id    pageviews
2015      1        100          29
2015      2        100          22
2015      3        100          178
2015      4        100          34
2015      1        200          56
2015      3        200          16
```

Here's the result I would like to have:

```
year    month   member_id    pageviews
2015      1        100          29
2015      2        100          22
2015      3        100          178
2015      4        100          34
2015      1        200          56
2015      2        200          0
2015      3        200          16
2015      4        200          0
```

In the result above, notice the additional rows with zero pageviews.

How do I get this result? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in the data:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM created_at) AS year,
       EXTRACT(month FROM created_at) AS month,
       m.member_id,
       COUNT(t.member_id) as pageviews
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(year FROM created_at) AS year, EXTRACT(month FROM created_at) AS month FROM TABLE) ym CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT member_id FROM TABLE) m LEFT JOIN
     TABLE t
     ON EXTRACT(year FROM created_at) AS month = ym.year AND
        EXTRACT(month FROM created_at) AS month = ym.month AND
        t.member_id = m.member_id
GROUP BY ym.year, ym.month, m.member_id
ORDER BY ym.year, ym.month, m.member_id;
```

This assumes that all year/month combinations are included in the table.

If you have other tables that are better sources for members and the dates, try them -- that may be faster than `SELECT DISTINCT`.